# MYSQL JOIN 3 tables where field in third tables must be 0 and nothing else

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

**story**

id, title

**categoryrelation**

storyId, categoryId

**category**

id, title, calm (boolean of 1 and 0)

I want to show all stories which have a category with the value 0 on calm

I can do that, but I don't want the query to show stories with categories with calm = 0 and calm = 1

Or better: Only show NOT calm stories, meaning don't show the story if any category of it has the value 1 on the calm field

What I currently have:

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, c.title, c.calm FROM story s LEFT JOIN categoryrelation 
cr ON (cr.storyId = s.id) LEFT JOIN category c ON (cr.categoryId = c.id AND 
(c.calm = 0 AND c.calm != 1)) WHERE s.parentStory IS NULL AND s.active = 1 
ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

It works, but also outputs stories with a category with calm = 1

Data sample:

**story**

1, teststory

2, anotherstory

**categoryrelation**

1, 1

1, 2

1, 3

2, 4

**category**

1, mystery, 0

2, thriller, 0

3, romance, 1

4, horror, 0

***Expected result:***

2, anotherstory

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by story and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT s.id, s.title
FROM story s 
LEFT JOIN categoryrelation cr ON (cr.storyId = s.id) 
LEFT JOIN category c ON cr.categoryId = c.id 
WHERE s.parentStory IS NULL AND s.active = 1 
GROUP BY s.id, s.title
HAVING MAX(c.calm) = 0
ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

The condition `MAX(c.calm) = 0` means that there is no category with `c.calm = 1`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/suarcS76CfTU4FeSoejxsw/0).
Results:

```
| id  | title        |
| --- | ------------ |
| 2   | anotherstory |
```

Comment: Hi, I want to output the stories, not the categories. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: This code outputs the stories. If you don't want the categories then remove group_concat(). I will edit.